# Hiding a program window from the open windows / running programs bar in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I have many Firefox windows open, and each one has its own instance in the Ubuntu open windows bar.

I'd like to selectively hide those which are taking up the limited space there. The window grouping feature isn't a solution since it prevents me from seeing just the 5-8 windows which I do need to have accessible from there.

Is there any way to control on a per-window basis what is visible and what not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Compiz, you can also use the "Windows Rules" options to make certain programs skip the taskbar altogether, depending on title, class, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the great application [Alltray](http://www.handexercise.org/). Install it using `sudo apt-get install alltray` and it should be under Applications->Accessories. When you open it, it'll prompt you to click on the window you want to put into the notification tray. That should work.